# PHP IF statement not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a PHP code that monitors my credits for our clients. If the client reaches 0 credits the php should not go to the desired page but to a page that will direct him to a notification page that he is low or has no credits

```
 <script>
 function validateForm()
 {
 var x=document.forms["lbs_trace"]["lbs_case"].value;
 var y=document.forms["lbs_trace"]["lbs_reason"].value;
 var count = 0;
   if (!(x==null || x==""))
   { 
     count++;
   }
   if (!(y==null || y==""))
   { 
      count++;
   }
   if(count < 2){
     alert("Please complete CASE / RA number and REASON for trace");
     return false;     
   }



 }
 </script>
   <?php
 // Database Passwords
 $host="localhost"; // Host name 
 $username="stingin_epanic"; // Mysql username 
 $password="*****"; // Mysql password 
 $db_name="*****"; // Database name 
 $tbl_name="TEST_credits"; // Table name 

 // Connect to server and select database.
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TEST_credits WHERE id='1'");
 ?>
   <?php
          $crds=0;
 while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 ?>
   <span class="blue11" style="font-size: 12px"><span class="blue11" style="font-size:    
   12px"> </span>
    <label for="credit"></label>
   <input type="text" name="credit" value="<?php echo $rows['credits']; ?>" id="credit"   
   />
   <?php
          if($rows['credits'] > 0)
            {
                $crds=1;
            }
         }
         if($crds==0)
            {
                header("Location:../main.php");
            }
         ?>
   </span> 
   <form method="post" action="../lbs/lbs_record.php" name="lbs_trace" onsubmit="return 
    validateForm()">
```

I had it working great all I added was the validateForm() to make sure that the fields are completed. Previously I just posted the form and it worked. Could this be the reason?

Comment: what happenens now ?? after you added the js validation?

Comment: It continues to the action="../lbs/lbs_record.php" page and should go to header("Location:../main.php"); which it is not doing. If there is 0 credits it should direct to main page

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things about your code.

When you want to get only one row, just use `mysql_fetch_array()`. You don't need loop for that.

Don't use deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Instead use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.

You can't set new header using `header()` function after sending anything to browser (so it have to be in first PHP block in your code). Move your JS to the bottom of file.

After using `header()` with `Location` you have to use `die()` to stop executing script. In other case, PHP will execute some more lines before redirect (or all, depends on server configuration).

In `header()` with `Location` you should use absolute URL. Read about it [in RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30).

After executing query, don't put result to `mysql_fetch_array()`. First check if everything is ok with it. In other case you'll miss error that could happen.

And the reason that your script is not working is lack of `return true` in your JS validation function (at the end, when everything is checked). Without it browser will think that validation failed and will not send request.